# meaning of "congress to the mayor's president"

Tags: meaning, sentence-usage

I'm trying to understand the following sentence:

> The (New York) city council is congress to the mayor's president.

Can anyone please teach me its meaning in a grammatical sense?
Also, what (who) does the "mayor's president" refer to?

I'm wondering if it means "the city council to the mayor is like Congress to the U.S. president”. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Previously posted on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529747/interpretation-of-congress-to-the-mayors-president).

Comment: The question on [english.se] might eventually be migrated here. If that happens this question will be a direct duplicate of the other one. As it stands, cross posting is highly discouraged for a multitude of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't mistaken! The sentence's wording is just a bit ambiguous. A more straightforward rephrasing of the sentence would be:

> The city council is to the mayor as Congress is to the President.

P.S. I see that this question has already been answered on EL&U, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to have it answered here too. Cheers!